# Rearranging data frame so that rows are cut and pasted as columns

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, data-manipulation

I do not know if I explained my intentions through the title, but in essence I want to **convert**

```
        mean    sd
v1  -32.72  0.565
v2  -50.47  1.543
v3  -30.17  0.9295
v4  -38.56  0.4541
g1  5.649   0.02509
g2  1.672   0.02992
g3  3.139   0.03507
g4  7.169   0.06703
y1  271.1   3.48
y2  123.7   1.81
y3  138.9   2.727
y4  405.5   4.396
```

**to**

```
 v.mean v.sd    g.mean  g.sd    y.mean  y.sd
-32.72  0.565   5.649   0.02509 271.1   3.48
-50.47  1.543   1.672   0.02992 123.7   1.81
-30.17  0.9295  3.139   0.03507 138.9   2.727
-38.56  0.4541  7.169   0.06703 405.5   4.396
```

I want to do so without using for loop. I feel that there is some `reshape` function that may do this. I have a large number of datasets with this configuration. So, I wanted to have some **vectorization** solution...
Also, the length can be anything. Here, in the sample data the series length is 4.
In addition, I am not picky with the column names. That I can achieve using `names(dataframe)=c(...`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is indeed a function named `reshape`. Supposing your data.frame is named "data", do the following to get the result you want:

```
data$group <- substr(rownames(data),1,1)
data$id <- substr(rownames(data),2,2)
result <- reshape(data, v.names=c("mean","sd"), idvar="id", timevar="group", direction="wide")
```

For details, see `?reshape`

Comment: Thanks for illustrating how to extract `reshape` information from rownames.

Answer (score 1):

using `reshap2`, we apply `acast` in a clever melted data.

```
dat <- read.table(text ='v1  -32.72  0.565
v2  -50.47  1.543
v3  -30.17  0.9295
v4  -38.56  0.4541
g1  5.649   0.02509
g2  1.672   0.02992
g3  3.139   0.03507
g4  7.169   0.06703
y1  271.1   3.48
y2  123.7   1.81
y3  138.9   2.727
y4  405.5   4.396')
colnames(dat) <- c('var','mean','sd')
```

First I melt my data:

```
dat.m <- melt(dat)
Using var as id variables
   var variable     value
1   v1     mean -32.72000
2   v2     mean -50.47000
3   v3     mean -30.17000
4   v4     mean -38.56000
5   g1     mean   5.64900
```

Now I want I need to split the var column to use just the letter of var in the future columns. Usually we use  `ColSplit` but here no visible pattern so I create the columns by hand and I apply `acast`

```
dat.m$vv <- substr(dat.m$var,1,1)
dat.m$key <- substr(dat.m$var,2,2)
acast(dat.m[,-1],id ~variable+vv)
  mean_g mean_v mean_y    sd_g   sd_v  sd_y
1  5.649 -32.72  271.1 0.02509 0.5650 3.480
2  1.672 -50.47  123.7 0.02992 1.5430 1.810
3  3.139 -30.17  138.9 0.03507 0.9295 2.727
4  7.169 -38.56  405.5 0.06703 0.4541 4.396
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very similar approach to @Theodore's answer. Assuming your dataset is called "dat":

```
reshape(cbind(dat, do.call(rbind, strsplit(rownames(dat), ""))), 
        idvar="2", timevar="1", direction = "wide")
#    2 mean.v   sd.v mean.g    sd.g mean.y  sd.y
# v1 1 -32.72 0.5650  5.649 0.02509  271.1 3.480
# v2 2 -50.47 1.5430  1.672 0.02992  123.7 1.810
# v3 3 -30.17 0.9295  3.139 0.03507  138.9 2.727
# v4 4 -38.56 0.4541  7.169 0.06703  405.5 4.396
```

In the above:

- `do.call(rbind, strsplit(rownames(dat), ""))` creates a two column matrix where the first column is the letters "v", "g", and "y", and the second, the numbers 1 through 4. This step probably oversimplifies similar problems since it only applies to two-character `rownames`; you would likely have to resort to some regex for more complicated scenarios.
- `cbind(...)` integrates this new matrix with your original `data.frame`; the new column names are simply "1" and "2".
- Your "time" variable is the new column that contains letters "v", "g", and "y" (the column named "2"); your "id" variable is the new column that contains the numbers 1 through 4 (the column named "1"). Use that information to `reshape()` your data.

An alternative to using the `reshape()` function once you've gotten your data to that stage is to use `aggregate()`:

```
aggregate(cbind(mean, sd) ~ `2`, 
          data = cbind(dat, do.call(rbind, strsplit(rownames(dat), ""))), 
          FUN = I)
  2  mean.1  mean.2  mean.3    sd.1    sd.2    sd.3
1 1 -32.720   5.649 271.100 0.56500 0.02509 3.48000
2 2 -50.470   1.672 123.700 1.54300 0.02992 1.81000
3 3 -30.170   3.139 138.900 0.92950 0.03507 2.72700
4 4 -38.560   7.169 405.500 0.45410 0.06703 4.39600
```